# How to run through each checked checkbox with a classname using JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an immediate equivalent in javascript for the below jquery code?

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //logic here
    }
});
```

I'm trying to run through all the checkboxes on a page with `class = 'checkbox'` - the client doesn't want to use jQuery, so I need an alternative for the above.

I'm hoping I can avoid writing a long function from scratch to do this and simply use something built-in to JavaScript, but it's looking like it's not possible.

Comment: If we could do something as simple as this without JQuery, why would we have JQuery.

Comment: @musefan customers don't always listen to arguments of sanity.

Comment: @JaredPar: I disagree... that should say "never" ;)

Comment: @musefan -- http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif ^_^

Comment: @Neal i can't tell if that's a spoof or a real SO question. Please say spoof.

Comment: @JaredPar read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: thank you for all the answers everyone, you've all been very helpful thanks for your time

Comment: You'd get much better answers if you posted the relevant markup for this problem. Are these form elements inside of a singular form?

Comment: i'm very satisfied with the answers below, i wasn't being sarcastic. it's not practical to post all the relevant code for this issue, it's quite large, but i appreciate the offer of your continued assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many older browsers don't support `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`, so you'd have to loop over all `<input>` elements in those browsers.  It's always best to check for those functions first, though.

Secondly, you should never use `$(this).is(":checked")` — *not even in jQuery* — it's a very slow path to take when looking for `this.checked`.

This should get you going:

```
var base = document,
    inps, tmp, i = 0, reg = /\bcheckbox\b/;

// getElementsByClassName is the fastest method
if (base.getElementsByClassName)
    inps = base.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
// Followed by querySelectorAll
else if (base.querySelectorAll)
    inps = base.querySelectorAll(".checkbox");
// But if neither exist, loop through all the elements and check the class
else {
    inps = [];
    var tmp = base.getElementsByTagName("input");
    i = tmp.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (reg.test(tmp[i].className)
            inps.push(tmp[i]);
    }
}

// Finally, loop through the matched elements and apply your logic
i = inps.length;
while (i--) {
    var current = inps[i];
    if (current.checked) {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

In the example above, you can change the value of `base` to any element.  This means that, if all these elements have a common parent or ancestor node, you can set that element as the base and it should run faster, e.g:

```
var base = document.getElementById("myForm");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
     if(checkboxes[i].checked){}
     else {}
}
```

See comments below. you can use `getElementsByTagName` for older versions of IE and other older browsers.

Comment: getElementsByClassName isn't supported in older versions of IE, although getElementsByTagName and getAttribute are.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var all = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  var current = all[i];
  if (current.checked) {
    // Logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of browser dependent then. But with a modern browser you'd use `document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')` to get an array that you'd iterate through, then `is(':checked')` becomes the more common `if(array[i].checked){}`.

Feel free to read about the [compatible browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html). You'll find that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 5.5, 6, and 7.

I think jQuery works around this in [sizzle about here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L848).

So it might look like:

```
var allCheckbox;
if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
  allCheckbox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
} else {
  allCheckbox = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*') {
  for (var j=0; j < all.length; j++) {
    //Comparison cribbed from sizzle
    if ((" " + (all[j].className || all[j].getAttribute("class")) + " ")
      .indexOf('checkbox') > -1
    ) {
      allCheckbox[i++] = all[j];
    }
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < allChecked.length; i++) {
  if (allChecked[i].checked) {
    // Logic here
  }
}
```

Final note: getElementsByTagName('*') doesn't work with Internet Explorer 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has built-in methods for getting DOM elements by ID, or by tag name, but selecting by class [isn't supported in older versions of IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements). However, it would be fairly fast to obtain all `input`s and test them for the `checkbox` type:

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].type === "checkbox" && x[i].checked) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You can also test if their class is "checkbox", but this gets complicated  if they have more than one class. If they don't:

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].className === "checkbox" && x[i].checked) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just use `x[i].type === "checkbox"`. Attributes are mapped to properties automatically.

Comment: @MattMcDonald Good point -- been awhile since I've had to do this without jQuery. Will fix.